# Backing up SQL Jobs for an Instance

Tags: backup, jobs

I would like to ensure that I have a backed up copy of every job on my SQL server 2008 R2 instance. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The jobs are themselves stored in `MSDB`:

I believe taking regular backups of system-- `MSDB` database should do good:

Else you can perform some manual stesps as listed below:

> 1. Start SQL Server Management Studio.
> 2. Expand the SQL Server Agent folder, and then expand the list of Jobs.
> 3. Right-click the job you want to create a backup script for, and then select Script Job as.
> 4. Click `CREATE` To or `DROP` To, then click New Query Editor Window, File, or Clipboard to select a destination for the script. Typically,
>      the destination is a file with a .sql extension.

Also, for multiple jobs to copy at one go:  In SSMS click on the Jobs folder under SQL Server Agent,  then go to Object Explorer Details.  You can select multiple jobs and script them all at the same time.

Comment: Note that when you script jobs from SSMS, this does not include schedules. You'll be able to recreate the jobs but will need to add schedules again.

Comment: @MatthewSwain thats not correct, when you script using the way KASQLDBA said, it will script out schedule as well `sp_add_jobschedule` (see the script at the bottom - when you script).

Comment: @Kin perhaps this depends on your SSMS version, I'm pretty sure they're not in older versions at least.

Comment: @MatthewSwain its always recommended best practice to use the latest 2014 SSMS to avoid any surprises.

Comment: @Mike, Please mark it as an answer if this resolves you're query so as to close the unflag thread as unanswered,